real numbers $a_{i,j}$ Prove $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i,j}^4\ge \left(\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i,j}^2\right)^2.$
I solved this problem, but I want to know if there's an easier or more magical solution for it.

Problem statement Let integer $n\ge 3,$ $\tbinom n2$ nonnegative real numbers $a_{i,j}$ satisfy $ a_{i,j}+a_{j,k}\le a_{i,k}$ for all $1\le i <j<k\le n$. Prove
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i,j}^4\ge \left(\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i,j}^2\right)^2.$$

My solution
I've heard this have something to do with this famous problem, the weaker bound of this is found in PFTB:
Let integer $n\ge 3,$ positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n$ satsify
$$(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)\left(\frac 1{x_1}+\frac 1{x_2}+\cdots +\frac 1{x_n}\right)=n^2+1.$$Prove that
$$(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2)\left(\frac 1{x_1^2}+\frac 1{x_2^2}+\cdots +\frac 1{x_n^2}\right)\ge n^2+4+\frac 4{n^2}.$$
I know how to prove the above problem, by this and Lagrange equation we can get
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^2=1.$$Also
\begin{align*}4+\frac 4{n^2}&\le\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left({\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^2\\&=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^2\left[\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^2+4\right]\\&=4+\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^4.\end{align*}Therefore
$$\frac{n^2}4\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^4\ge\left[\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}\right)^2\right]^2$$Seems like if $a_{i,j}=\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_j}}-\sqrt{\frac{x_j}{x_i}}$ there is some relationship... when $n$ is even it can be proved this way.

This is from the 2024 China TST. Discussion is allowed, just making note of this.

@TheBestMagician Yeah, I know. The discussion is allowed because the content ended a long time ago.
